# how can I edit code snippet cursor position JSON

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

My code snippets is;

```
  "echo": {
      "prefix": "echo",
      "body": [
          "echo \"\";"
      ],
      "description": "a"
  }
```

How I get cursor position in double quotes?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$0` signals the location of the final cursor stop

```
"echo": {
      "prefix": "echo",
      "body": [
          "echo \"$0\";"
      ],
      "description": "a"
  }
```